# Why is my UIPanGestureRecognizer not working properly in my UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition class?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom `UITabBarController` with a custom transition (i.e.`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`). I decided to make it all interactive with a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`. The problem? No matter what I try in the `.began` clause, the interactivity either stops working or (as presented in the code below) the gesture recognizer works only in the horizontal direction (I need this but how does it know??) but only in the left to right direction (and I need the opposite). Any help?

Here is the code for my custom tab bar controller class that matters:

```
class FloatingTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

private let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
var interactor = FloatingTabBarPercentDrivenInteraction()
var floatingView = FloatingTabBarView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.delegate = self
       self.tabBar.isHidden = true

       self.selectedIndex = 0

       self.addTabBarIcons()

       floatingView = FloatingTabBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height - 54 - 36, width: screenSize.width*0.274666666, height: 54))
       floatingView.center.x = self.tabBar.center.x

       floatingView.datasource = self
       floatingView.delegate = self
       floatingView.setup()

       interactor.wireToViewController(viewController: self)
       self.view.addSubview(floatingView)
    }
}

extension FloatingTabBarViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return FloatingTabBarAnimatedTransitioning()
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactor.interactionInProgress ? interactor : nil
    }
}
```

And here is my `UIPercentDrivenInteractionTransition` class:

```
class FloatingTabBarPercentDrivenInteraction: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {

    var interactionInProgress = false
    private var shouldCompleteTransition = false
    private weak var tabBarViewController: FloatingTabBarViewController!

    func wireToViewController(viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.tabBarViewController = viewController as! FloatingTabBarViewController
        prepareGestureRecognizerInView(view: viewController.view)
    }

    private func prepareGestureRecognizerInView(view: UIView) {
        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(gestureRecognizer:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func handleGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view)
        var progress = (translation.x / 200)
        progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))

        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
           interactionInProgress = true
           tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 1
        case .changed:
            shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.3
            update(progress)
        case .cancelled:
            interactionInProgress = false
            cancel()
        case.ended:
            interactionInProgress = false
            if !shouldCompleteTransition {
                cancel()
            } else {
                finish()
            }
        default:
            print("Unsupported")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `translation.x`. If you want vertical, you probably want `translation.y`.

Comment: @brandonscript I do want a horizontal translation. But for some reason the gesture only works if my finger is swiping from left to right even though I never specifically coded it that way.

Comment: I'd get it working without the horizontal constraint to see if that's blocking the vertical motion?

Comment: "gesture only works if my finger is swiping from left to right" ... Yep, you're calculating `progress` as `translation(in:)` divided by 200, limited to the range of 0 to 1. So, by definition, you're only detecting left to right gestures. If you want to detect right to left, you better handle negative `translation(in:)`...

Comment: @Rob yup figured it out, I just forgot to update my question here. Thanks though!